# ASP.NET Web Api - "PATCH" using Delta<...> with double property not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, delta

From JavaScript client code I am creating the following data:

```
    var employee = {
        FirstName: "Rudolf",
        Salary: 99
    };
```

I then pass this through an Ajax call to an MVC Web API Controller Action:

```
using System.Web.Http.OData;

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromUri] int employeeId, [FromBody] Delta<Employee> employee)
    {
        await _employeeService.Patch(employeeId, employee);
        return Ok();
    }
```

This calls my service to update the database as follows:

```
    public async Task Patch(int employeeId, Delta<Employee> employee)
    {
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            if (employee.TryGetPropertyValue("Salary", out object salary))
            {
                var ss = Convert.ToDouble(salary); // Always 0
            }

            if (employee.TryGetPropertyValue("FirstName", out object firstName))
            {
                var ss = Convert.ToString(firstName); // Expected value
            }

            var currentEmployee = await context.Employees
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == employeeId);

            if (currentEmployee == null)
                return;

            employee.Patch(currentEmployee);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

**Note:**  I missed out some of the details for brevity as the actual client-server call is working fine.

The code seems to work as expected, but the Salary property (the only none-string one) is always set to 0 (zero).  So that field never get's updated.

Any ideas why the Salary is not being passed through?

**Note**: I use very similar client-server code for GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and they all work fine, so I believe it is related to the Delta<> part.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I encountered the same problem with `int` properties.

I solved the problem using [SimplePatch](https://github.com/OmarMuscatello/SimplePatch) (v1.0 is only 10KB).

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the project.

It is inspired to [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData) but [SimplePatch](https://github.com/OmarMuscatello/SimplePatch) has no dependencies.

**How to use**
Install the package using:

```
Install-Package SimplePatch
```

Your MVC Web API Controller Action becomes:

```
using SimplePatch;

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromUri] int employeeId, [FromBody] Delta<Employee> employee)
{
    await _employeeService.Patch(employeeId, employee);
    return Ok();
}
```

Then your `Patch` method becomes:

```
public async Task Patch(int employeeId, Delta<Employee> employee)
{
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    {
        if (employee.TryGetPropertyValue("Salary", out object salary))
        {
            var ss = Convert.ToDouble(salary);
        }

        if (employee.TryGetPropertyValue("FirstName", out object firstName))
        {
            var ss = Convert.ToString(firstName);
        }

        var currentEmployee = await context.Employees
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == employeeId);

        if (currentEmployee == null)
            return;

        employee.Patch(currentEmployee);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Also, [SimplePatch](https://github.com/OmarMuscatello/SimplePatch) gives you the ability to ignore some properties when calling the `Patch` method.

**Global.asax** or **Startup.cs**

```
DeltaConfig.Init((cfg) =>
{
    cfg.ExcludeProperties<Employee>(x => x.YourPropertyName);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Salary` has type `int` then there is an issue with that type

The Json parser converts integers to 64 bit ones, which won't match the 32 bit `int` properties declared on the entity and thus get ignored by this method.

This problem is mentioned [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/562)

So, you can use `long` instead of `int` or using the OData media type formatters
See [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/easy-asp-net-web-api-resource-updates-with-delta/)

Comment: How can we tell the Json parser to use int32 ?

Comment: You can use ODataMediaTypeFormatter or third party libraries